# access denied preferred over no view

Tags: nodes, users

How can I make it so roles that are denied access to a page can still see overview of page i.e. title and description but get an access denied message if not granted access?

I have tried different combinations of per node access along with content access but because in permissions there is only a view published content for all content which if deselected renders every page access denied regardless of content or node access...my only option it seems is the invisible page for no content access which is not at all preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Premium content](https://drupal.org/project/premium_content)  Module..

Project Page Says

> This is useful on a news or membership site where teasers are
>   available to the general public but the full body is only available to
>   privileged users. Premium nodes appear in listings with full title and
>   teaser available to anyone. If a user does not have adequate
>   privileges, the default behavior is to show a simple message, but you
>   can use Panels or theme overrides to do more custom things.

Found this [article](https://drupal.org/node/677644) in D.O which will be useful for your issue.

Comment: Excellent thank you for this. I also thought of a workaround where I create extra content types mirroring the real pages and access to certain roles but the above looks far more productive!